# What does ps axuwfw return?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, tmux, ps

I am getting strange output including my old makefile output and process tree when running below command on linux

`ps axuwfw`

Also, what is the usefulness of the following command and how does it works?

`ps axuwfw | grep -v grep | grep -i screen`

`ps axuwfw | grep -v grep | grep -i tmux`

The above two commands return 431 and 7 in the example from [here](http://www.slideshare.net/matsubokkuri/20130215-tmux), but in my system it returns some previously ran older makefile output and truncated process tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ps axuwfw
```

This is a combination of several BSD-style options (all of which are in the manual page, `man ps`):

- `a`: include processes from other users
- `x`: include processes with no terminal
- `u`: show user-oriented information fields
- `w`: wide output (132 columns instead of 80)
- `f`: "forest": tree view of processes
- `w`: even wider output (no limit at all)

In other words, it simply shows currently running processes.

However, if you see *old* processes there, check their "STAT" field – if it says `Z`, the process has exited but its parent hasn't "reaped" it yet; the process is a "zombie". This usually indicates that the parent process is either slightly buggy, or has hung/crashed.

Also, note that not all operating systems accept these options. On SysV it might be `ps -ef`.

```
ps axuwfw | grep -v grep | grep -i screen
```

The `|` is a pipe. It redirects one command's output to the other's input. This should make it more obvious that the above is not just one weird magical command; it is three commands connected.

1. The first command, `ps axuwfw`, was already explained.
2. `grep`, is for searching/filtering text. `grep foo` would only print input lines that contain the text "foo". With the `-v` option, the second command – `grep -v …` – does the opposite – prints lines that do *not* match. (Again, refer to `man grep` or `grep --help`.)

   This particular invocation is necessary because all processes in a pipeline run at the same time, so the `ps…` would show all `grep…` processes – and `ps axu | grep screen` would cause the `grep…` to also match its own entry in addition to the desired ones. So a second `grep…` is added to explicitly ignore lines that have "grep" in them.

   (Of course, there are better tools, like `pgrep -alf screen`, but many people still use this kind of `ps|grep|grep…` pipeline just because it's easy to combine knowing just `ps` and `grep`.)
3. The third command, `grep -i screen`, again just extracts lines that contain "screen".

   As described in both the manual page and the `grep --help` output, adding the `-i` option makes the search case-insensitive, so it also outputs lines that have "Screen" or "SCREEN" in them.

In short, the full command just prints those `ps…` lines that talk about the "screen" program.

> "The above two commands return 431 and 7 in the example from here…"

They don't. They return information about processes named "screen" or "tmux". The number given in the example is the *count* of processes returned.

The slideshow's author didn't include the full output (which isn't really relevant); they only included the total counts as a summary, demonstrating that there are 60 times more "screen" users than "tmux" users.

If you want the command to actually count lines for you, you can a) add the `-c` (count) option to the *last* `grep…` command, or b) pipe it through `| wc -l`. (Either works.)

---

> "…but in my system it returns garbage."

---

> It returns some previously ran older makefile output and truncated process tree

That's not garbage – it's exactly the output you asked it for.

Comment: This answer is really informative. The information about the STAT field in ps output is really new for me. Thanks!